# VBA Error Handling

Tags: vba, error-handling

I'm new to VBA and I have a question about Error Handling...

I have code in the following setup.

```
Sub code()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    'bunch of code (real code that's running)

    CurrentRow = 1/0
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    'Error Handling (uses a msgbox and vbyesno)
```

For some reason my code isn't going to the ErrorHandler, but rather it is popping up the normal debug error, Run-time error '11':

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the VBA Editor;

Tools -> Options -> General

Set *Error Trapping* to *Break on unhanded errors*.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I have that as the setting.   I've been toying around with it some more, and I have found that if I place an error directly after the On Error Goto ErrorHandler, I get the desired response.  But not if my error is near the end of my code.

Comment: Do you disable error handling after the `on error goto` with `on error resume next` at some point?